# extract/separate duration value from postgresql log in elk

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have elk(elasticsearch, logstash , kibana) for monitor logs.
 postgresql logs with filebeat send to logstash and show logs in kibana.
I enabled log_duration in postgresql.conf and logged correctly.
for example, the postgresql log is below :

```
2023-01-11 06:17:09.754 EST [19751] user@books LOG:  duration: 0.014 ms  execute <unnamed>: SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY
2023-01-11 06:17:09.755 EST [19751] user@books LOG:  duration: 0.016 ms  bind S_1: BEGIN
2023-01-11 06:17:09.755 EST [19751] user@books LOG:  duration: 0.006 ms  execute S_1: BEGIN
2023-01-11 06:17:09.756 EST [19751] user@books LOG:  duration: 0.488 ms  parse <unnamed>: select * from books
```

but in kibana, The duration value of the field is not separate and it is displayed as one with the message field, and there is no possibility of aggregation and other opetaions.
[image]

how to extract and split duration value from message ???